# Printing each number in new line in Scheme

Tags: arrays, printing, scheme

I need a help to convert this Pascal code to Scheme code:

```
program reverseorder;
type
arraytype = array [1..5] of integer;

var
arr:arraytype;
i:integer;

begin

for i:=1 to 5 do
    arr[i]:=i;

for i:=5 downto 1 do
    writeln(arr[i]);
    
end.
```

I want to accesses to a specific atom and its seems there aren't iteration method in Scheme.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to iterate over a list in Scheme :) what interpreter are you using? Racket, Chez, other?

Comment: I used this online interpreter (gauche):https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_scheme_online.php

Comment: Ouch, that doesn't give us too many options, it's a basic implementation of the Scheme standard with few looping constructs, not the best way to learn the language IMHO. Better download an interpreter with more features, I suggest Racket for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to tackle this problem. With the online interpreter you're using you'll be limited to vanilla Scheme, and the solution will be more verbose than needed, using recursion:

```
(define lst '(1 2 3 4 5))

(let loop ((rev (reverse lst)))
  (when (not (null? rev))
    (display (car rev))
    (newline)
    (loop (cdr rev))))
```

With Racket, which is aimed at beginners, you can write a much simpler (albeit non-standard) solution:

```
(define lst (range 1 6))

(for ([e (reverse lst)])
  (displayln e))
```

Either way, notice that the procedure for reversing a list is already built in the language, and you don't need to reimplement it - naturally, it's called `reverse`. And if it wasn't obvious already, in Scheme we prefer to use *lists*, not arrays to represent a sequence of elements - it's recommended to stop thinking in terms of indexes, array lengths, etc. because that's not how things are done in Scheme.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Because I am studying a course for CS field and I need to have a knowledge of fundamental of functional language. and that's why I have to work with the standrad Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about returned value (it's `#<undef>`) and just want to produce output, you can use `for-each`:

```
(for-each print (reverse (list 1 2 3 4 5)))

Output:
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not idiomatic Scheme, but a literal translation of the Pascal code would be:

```
(let ([arr (make-vector 5)])
     (do ([i 0 (+ i 1)]) ((= i 5)) (vector-set! arr i i))
     (do ([i 4 (- i 1)]) ((negative? i))
         (display (vector-ref arr i))
         (newline)))
```